# Can I sort a Sharepoint list before I start loop through the list items?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

is it possible for me to sort a sharepoint list by date or by creator then I start to loop through it to retrieve data?

Also, is it possible to do a count after I group a list of items together. For example, I'll group the items by the creator, then check how many of these items are there.

I think i'm asking more than 1 questions here, please let me know if I should start another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these things are possible when you use **LINQ to SharePoint**.

Example from [Using LINQ to SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535491.aspx):

```
// Get DataContext from page context
DataContext data = new DataContext(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);

// Get the SharePoint list
EntityList<Customer> Customers = data.GetList<Customer>("Customers");

// Query for customers from London
var londonCustomers = from customer in Customers
                      where customer.City == "London"
                      select customer;

foreach (var londonCust in londonCustomers)
{
    Console.Writeline("id = {0}, City = {1}", londonCust.CustomerId, londonCust.City);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466353.aspx) for this, e.g.

[OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms467378.aspx) or [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415157.aspx)

```
SPList list = ...; //your list;
var query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<OrderBy> <FieldRef Name="Your field"/> </OrderBy>" 
//or
query.Query = "<GroupBy> <FieldRef Name="Your field"/> </GroupBy>"
var items = list.GetItems(query);
foreach(var item in items)
{
  //do your work
}
```

But for counting of the grouped items there is no direct OOB way. When you get item from query you could get it's count from the item collection.